# Is it possible to remap Command-N in Catalina's Safari?

Tags: keyboard, safari, catalina

I used to remap <kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>N</kbd> in Yosemite's Safari to New Private Window, but Catalina's Safari doesn't seem to allow this.

Has anybody figured out the voodoo to get this to work? Thanks

Comment: Please post your remapping's screenshot.

Comment: I am using command+P replacing its original shortcut for Private Browsing. Never done with N I also tested a lot on it. Any other key works with command + xx, but when I mapped N from Keyboard shortcut, it may be counterfeiting with other inbuilt setups. I try to change New Windows to other and New Private Window to command+N, but it still doesn't work. However, other alphabets beside N works smoothly which is interesting to dig out.

Comment: Command-N seems hardwired for whatever reason. The menu item's shortcut changes to what I want, but command-N will open a normal browsing window no matter what